# popup in a popup, second popup has no focus?

Tags: javascript, popup

Ok I know this is going to sound weird but it is what the client wants. I am working within a popup and when a user clicks on a datagrid cell within a certain column it will popup a html table with data. I have the second popup to display but it does not get focus. This is currently the code I am using to create the second popup. Any help to get the focus on this second popup would be great.

```
function onCellClick() {

        var cmGrid = igtbl_getGridById("countermeasureDetailsGrid");
        var cmCellID = cmGrid.ActiveCell.split("_");
        if (cmCellID[3] === "3") {
            var countermeasureID = igtbl_getCellById("countermeasureDetailsGrid_rc_" + cmCellID[2] + "_0").getValue();
            var recordType = igtbl_getCellById("countermeasureDetailsGrid_rc_" + cmCellID[2] + "_4").getValue();
            _crfPopupWindow = new crfPopupWindow(countermeasureID, recordType);

            _crfPopupWindow.open();
            _crfPopupWindow.focus();
        }
    }

    function crfPopupWindow(countermeasureID, recordType) {
        var crfPopup = new WindowDef();
        crfPopup.target = "CRF_Popup.aspx?countermeasureID=" + countermeasureID + "&" + "recordType=" + recordType;
        crfPopup.windowName = "CRFPopup";
        crfPopup.toolBar = "no";
        crfPopup.resizable = "yes";
        crfPopup.scrollbars = "yes";
        crfPopup.location = "yes";
        crfPopup.width = 350;
        crfPopup.height = 400;
        return crfPopup;
    }
```

EDIT: Solution

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function init() {
        window.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `it is what the client wants` -- Heard this _too_ often. Makes for horrible webpages =P

Comment: do you get an error (see the console or firebug or...)

Comment: no there is no error. The second pop up comes up it just hides behind the other windows.

Comment: lol I am an idiot why didn't I think to do window.focus on page load. That worked perfectly...even if I don't like a window with a popup and then another pop up lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.focus on page load  This works

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the 2nd popup has higher [z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)?

First popup can have z-index of, say, 1000, but the second should have then 1001.

Comment: this almost worked. The second popup come forward ahead of the original window but still hid behind the first pop up. I set the z-index in the first popup to 10 and the second popup to 11