# Javascript make HTML Table Clickable with Pop Up Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi currently I have a table which I would like for when a user clicks on a cell to open up a pop up window how would achieve this ? is there any sort of example/source code available. an example of a table cell looks like this:
[image]

Basically I would like for when the user selects the mitsubishi cell within the HTML Table to open up a pop up window maybe with a tickbox or textbox etc. Any help would be great being new to Javascript etc

Comment: I guess searching this site for previous similar questions would have avoided duplicity: [Pass data to popup of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408536/javascript-popup-in-html-table), [Popup when clicking canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182281/open-popup-when-click-inside-canvas-circle), [popup in a popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669731/popup-in-a-popup-second-popup-has-no-focus), [popup on a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559969/html-javascript-popup-box-with-table), ... This Q is well phrased and formatted and maybe should be preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
        $('#dialog').html($(this).html()); 
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="dialog" title="Example1"> <p>Example1</p>
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="dialog" > <p>Example2</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="dialog" ><p>Example3</p></td>
      <td class="dialog" ><p>Example4</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just one quick question how would I be able to edit the dialog box info and maybe add a tickbox etc ? Secondly your dialog box takes the same text from the table cells how can I make this different so that different text appears in the dialog box rather than using the tables

Comment: How Am I able to get rid of the table row text that automatically is shown within the DialogBox, I'd much rather be able to enter my own text for the Dialog box specifically

Answer (score 1):

For a large table with dynamically-added rows, some of which have images and some that don't, the following adaptation of https://jsfiddle.net/chin/2y4s4/ has worked for me:

```
// click on a row to pop up the image
$('#table_id').on('click','tr', function(e) {

    var image = $(e.currentTarget).find('a').attr('rel');
    if (typeof image === "undefined") {
    } else {
        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // dynamically create a <p> element with the image in it
        $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+ image  +"' alt='url preview' /></p>");
        $("#screenshot")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
    }
    e = null; 
});

// click on the image to get rid of it
$("body").on('click',"#screenshot", function(e) {$("#screenshot").remove()});
```

The CSS is

```
/* pop-up box of image on row-click */
    #screenshot{
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#333;
        padding:5px;
        display:none;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

And the dynamically-added table row is of the format

```
<tr><td>...</td><td style="display:none;">swamp_azalea.jpg<a href="https://georgefisher.com/flowers/" class="screenshot" rel="https://georgefisher.com/flowers/screenshots/swamp_azalea.jpg"></a></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a popup box when clicking the td tab area. Use this reference link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

You should add the belowline inside canvas tag

```
onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
```

i.e.,

```
<td id="myCanvas" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" >
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</td>
```

and create two div with id as 'light' and 'fade'

```
<div id="light" class="white_content"><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a><p>Content goes here</p></div>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></div>
```

and write the css like below.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .black_overlay{
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 10%;
left: 25%;
width: 50%;
height: 500px;
padding: 16px;
border: 13px solid #808080;
background-color: white;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use jQuery.

First of all you have to give the cell an html property id like this:

```
<markup id="cell_id"></markup>
```

Then you have to make a div container which will be the block displayed after somebody clicks the cell.

```
<div id="div_id">some text/images/etc. to appear in the block</div>
```

Now Here's your jQuery code:

```
$('#cell_id').click(function(){$('#div_id').toggle();});
```

Remember to set the div's css property display to none!

```
#div_id {display:none;}
```

Also you should enclose all your jQuery code within this:

```
$(function({/*your jQuery code*/}));
```

This will make the code be run after the whole webpage is downloaded.

Sorry for formatting. I'm testing out the StackExchange mobile app and am not yet familiar with it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution within the table by the use of JQuery. my cells and table are all layered into a div item and then a parent div also the cells are draggable meaning the user can drag a cell and put it into a specific place though I shall give this code a try. thanks !

Comment: Remember you have to add some css to the div to make it look like a box (though I won't help you with that, because I don't know how would you like it to look exactly) ;).

Comment: I understand I already have the cells looking like a box the only problem is that with the divs I first have a div class, then inside this class i have the table cells which are assigned to a div class known as "item". the only problem being is how can i integrate that into my jquery code?